# print jsp variable in browser console

Tags: java, json, jsp

in jsp I do `<p>${ob}</p>` I can get the object, but it's hard to read as the object size is not small. Can I print it using javascript? It's an email so I don't think I can use javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this :

```
console.log("${ob}");
```

> Don't forget `double Quotes` else by JS it would be  interpreted as a
>   variable name

Comment: tried but nothing come out. I think it's because I'm in email. I don't mind it's printed in html.